# How do I allow the request with this path to pass the webmock?

Tags: ruby, webmock

I want to mock NetHTTP requests but some should be allowed.

```
require "open-uri"    
require "webmock"
WebMock.enable!
```

When I declare an allowed request like this:

```
WebMock.disable_net_connect! allow: /\Ahttps:\/\/graph\.facebook\.com\/v2\.8\/debug_token\?access_token=/
```

and call:

```
open("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/debug_token?access_token=qwerty", &:read)
```

I get this:

> HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/debug_token?access_token=qwerty with headers ...
>   You can stub this request with the following snippet:
>   `stub_request(:get, "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/debug_token?access_token=qwerty").`
>   ...

It also fails with regex like this:

```
/\Ahttps:\/\/graph\.facebook\.com\//
```

but does not fail with this:

```
/\Ahttps:\/\/graph\.facebook\.com/
```

---

How to allow the full regex that I initially wanted? Why even the `\/` after hostname fails matching?

Comment: That's very strange. I tried opening a console and running those commands, in that order, and I got the correct behavior... Are you positive the `disable_net_connect!` line is being run before the `open`?

Comment: @Glyoko https://gist.github.com/Nakilon/d8a2f473d7675c590e69fc1b45dfaf44

Comment: Very strange... I'm getting `OpenURI::HTTPError: 400 Bad Request` which is correct, since the access_token is fake. Sorry, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of Webmock (1.22.6) has a bug when using open-uri:

https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/600

You can fix this bug by updating your webmock gem to the latest 1.x or 2.x